# Google Calendar API - (403) Access Not Configured'

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have developed an application which uses the Google Calendar API.

When I moved it from my development environment to a test environment, I created new entries for it in the Google API console, and copied that info into the config.php.

```
// The application_name is included in the User-Agent HTTP header.
'application_name' => 'Google Calendar PHP Starter Application',

// OAuth2 Settings, you can get these keys at https://code.google.com/apis/console
'oauth2_client_id' => '517034425134-503uog3i6pfXk15qq6mjsfbi48sabd50o.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'oauth2_client_secret' => '4p4go-aRXVcGx4YxcgC2wgvyV',
'oauth2_redirect_uri' => 'http://mydomain/admin/calendar_events.php',

// The developer key, you get this at https://code.google.com/apis/console
'developer_key' => 'AIzaSyCm9tj17rd-OepTl5XFxMwI9SQMH2BoQkKI',
```

However, I have no access.  I am getting:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key=AIzaSyCm9tj17rd-OepTl5XFxMwI9SQMH2BoQkKI: (403) Access Not Configured'
```

I'm not sure why this is.  I know the code is good... I just need to get something sync'd between their API console and my config.php, right?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to comment this line:

// 'developer_key' => 'AIzaSyCm9tj17rd-OepTl5XFxMwI9SQMH2BoQkKI',

Then it worked.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me in Blogger API too. But can you tell what was this line for ?

Answer (score 3):

After turning on the service (under Google Api's "Services" tab) I had to wait a few minutes before the authentication successfully kicked in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and enable switch for Calendar API.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the Calendar API on in the Services tab:
http://screencast.com/t/DbfpznnOT